# Image/file upload in CKEditor in HTA

Tags: ckeditor, hta

I'm creating an HTA based mostly on VBScript, Javascript, JQuery and HTML. The script is only for local use on my laptop. I have included CKEditor and I would like to add the feature of uploading images and/or files through CKEditor Image function without having to include plugins like CKFinder and similar file browsers.

I have tried various methods for enabling the upload script, but I can't get it to work. Recently I have tried the script on the following link, with no luck: https://github.com/AlfonsoML/CKEditorUploader
This script comes with different methods (PHP, C# and Vb.net) and I've tried all of them by following the readme file, but they do not seem to work.

```
Dim basePath As String = "C:\\Users\\Username\\Desktop\\Opslag\\upload
Dim baseUrl As String = "/images/"
```

I've changed the two strings above a dozen times with no luck either.

I have no idea whether this is possible or not since the scripts are not hosted on a server, but only run on a client computer (my own computer).

Is there any way for me to get the above mentioned script to work or any other script that works the same way? I hope my question is clear.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Those scripts are meant to be run on a server. If you use a hta then they won't work for you because they aren't being run at all, no matter what you change in them.

Comment: Thank you for your reply @AlfonsoML. So there is no way for me to get it to function as if it was running on a server?

Comment: I don't know what are the options that you can use with vbscript, but those scripts are for other languages and a hosting server. You might be able to override the need for a server and write everything in your HTA, but I have never tried that. Why don't you use a normal application instead of creating such complex system?

Comment: The HTA is perfect for my work station which is an offline computer. The script contains various notes which are listed in a database, so the script functions as a search database for my notes. I wish to have rich text in the notes and CKEditor supply that and works perfectly - well almost.